# ASP.NET Core SPA with React how to get render data in index.cshtml

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am making ASP.NET Core SPA with React in this project call react index.js call from index.cshtml in HomeController
there are error to call index.js in index.cshtml

this is index.cshtml code how to call index.js in this file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script src="~/ClientApp/src/index.js"></script>
```

this is index.js code below

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import Home from './Home';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('mydiv'));
root.render(
   <React.StrictMode>
     <Home/>
   </React.StrictMode>
);
```

this is Home.js code below

```
import React from "react";
const Home = () => {
    return <h1>Hello React Home</h1>;
};

export default Home;
```

how to get this Home output in index.cshtml
there are getting this output error in src
this src path give is correct but output not get
in this case react run on https://localhost:444620 and controller run on https://localhost:7122